# Tracert Enigma, timeout x4 days, possibility of redirecting?

Tags: networking, connection, adsl-router

Odd Question here.
I've run a MUD (based in OHIO) for close to a decade, and have yet to run into this problem before.

Since last friday, I have been unable to connect to the mud/box. IP: 66.167.82.254

Tracert gives:
        Tracing route to h-66-167-82-254.chcgilgm.static.covad.net [66.167.82.254]
        over a maximum of 30 hops:

```
      1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  BETTERTHANARIB [192.168.0.1]
      2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
      3    33 ms    36 ms    34 ms  dr03.chtn.wv.frontiernet.net [184.19.254.255]
      4    38 ms    47 ms    78 ms  static-184-19-254-4.chtn.wv.frontiernet.net [184.19.254.4]
      5    29 ms    36 ms    41 ms  184.13.127.141
      6    72 ms    79 ms    83 ms  ae4---0.cor02.chcg.il.frontiernet.net [74.40.1.53]
      7    69 ms     *       75 ms  ae1---0.cor01.asbn.va.frontiernet.net [74.40.2.194]
      8    64 ms    62 ms    62 ms  ae1---0.cbr01.asbn.va.frontiernet.net [74.40.2.174]
      9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     10   101 ms    98 ms   103 ms  ae3-10.c01.ash.bb.megapath.net [155.229.57.180]
     11    68 ms    72 ms    74 ms  ae8-0.asbnvacz-mxc2.bb.megapath.net [155.229.101.149]
     12   112 ms   112 ms   110 ms  ae2-0.chcgilgb-mxc2.bb.megapath.net [155.229.101.169]
     13    91 ms    85 ms    81 ms  ae0-0.chcgilgb-mxc1.bb.megapath.net [155.229.57.21]
     14   110 ms     *       84 ms  h-64-105-145-17.chcgilgm.static.covad.net [64.105.145.17]
     15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
     19  ^C
    C:\Users\PickleMe>ping 66.167.82.254

    Pinging 66.167.82.254 with 32 bytes of data:
            Request timed out.
            Request timed out.
            Request timed out.
            Request timed out.

    Ping statistics for 66.167.82.254:
        Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Now, this has been going on for 4 days in a row, and my ISP stated tonight that anything past hop #14 is not on their network and therefore out of their hands.

They had me fiddle with the TCP settings / manual & alternative DNS servers without any change in the result.

I killed every program I had running that wasn't essential as well as ran safe-mode with networking without any change.

What steps are available at this point?

The box is up, can connect to it from my iPhone via telnet and mud app.

A traceroute from work does just fine too. There is also an applet we built into the MUDs website that I can connect through. I just cannot connect straight through my pc's

Comment: Nothing on your PC will cause this to happen, nor would anything at your ISP.  The problem is at the other end - do you know that the box is up?  Have you spoken to those hosting the server the MUD is on?  I see it fail at the same point in the trace.  What protocol do you normally connect on - telnet?

Comment: The box is up, can connect to it from my iPhone via telnet and mud app. A tracery from work does just fine too. There is also an applet we built into the MUDs website that I can connect through. I just cannot connect straight through my pc's.....

Answer (score 0):

The IP address provided was tested from several points around the world, and all of them fail telnet, all of them traceroute to the same position or one hop less than the provided traceroute before timing out..

The issue is most likely a firewall or other restriction on the server itself, or immediately prior to it in the routing path.

This is not a local problem with your connection.